# how can i remove ? from my dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to remove `_` from my dataset. I have changed them to `NaN` and tried using the `dropna` function but it's not working.

I have also tried doing `dropna(how = "any")` it's still not working any idea how to?

**My code :**

`new_data1 = data_2.dropna(axis = 0)`

Comment: what do you want? The question is not clear. Do you want to delete a dataframe? just give `del df`

Comment: May be `NaN` is treated as string value. that's why dropna didn't work use `np.nan` for replacing `_` @JoeFerndz: I have edited OP question